# Which is the equivalent header file of MSCorEE.h in mono compiler?

Tags: c#, c++, linux, mono, clr

Could someone, please, tell me where to find MSCorEE.h and corerror.h (or equivalents) in mono compiler (Linux systems). 
I am trying to compile a code which initiates C# CLR from the native code, it works fine with VC compiler on windows, however, I am not able to find appropriate headers for mono compiler on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to embed mono in a native application.

You have to do something like this

```
#include <mono/jit/jit.h>
#include <mono/metadata/environment.h>
#include <mono/metadata/mono-config.h>
#include <mono/utils/mono-logger.h>
#include <mono/metadata/assembly.h>


void InitMonoCrt()
{

    mono_config_parse (NULL);

    domain = mono_jit_init ( "Nameofyourassembly.dll" );

    /* More stuff as needed */

}
```

http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono has more details on how to do it.

A simple example is here

http://go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=xhtml%3adeploy%2fmono-api-embedding.html